# Cant get output of command to command line itself?

Tags: windows, cmd, command, output

I have a command typed in the command line for example: -

```
     texteditor --help
```

This command executes and a window flashes and no output is given on the command line when i am expecting one. On further inspection i find that the command does give an output which i get through

```
     texteditor --help > output.txt
```

This means that the command does yield an output. I have also included the path in the Environment Variables. How can i give the output to the cmd without reading from the file i.e. that i type

```
texteditor --help
```

and get the output in the same console itself.

Comment: Are you typing this in a cmd window?

Comment: yes, i am. as suggested by the windows tag.

Comment: The executable is the problem, if you are at a cmd prompt.  You can try opening an elevated administrator cmd console to see if that changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED AGAIN**

I can only imagine the texteditor program is writing to a non-standard place. Normally, programs write normal messages to stdout (stream 1) and write error messages to stderr (stream 2). I obviously do not know what your particular program does, so to investigate it, I would do this:

```
texteditor --help 2> str2.txt 1> str1.txt
```

Thne you will have two files, `str2.txt` and `str1.txt`. Depending on what each contains afterwards, you should be able to see which stream you need to capture.

**EDITED**

In the light of your comment, maybe try this to output to console:

```
texteditor --help > con
```

I am not sure I understand what you mean by "How can I give the output to the cmd", but you can save the output of the command into the Windows Clipboard ready to paste into other applications like this:

```
texteditor --help | CLIP
```

Comment: As the description says, the output of the command isnt printing on the command line console from where i executed it. How can i get the output of the command without using a file or CLIP? What i require is that i write texteditor --help and get the output on the same console.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: hey mark, i tried the command you suggested (texteditor --help > con) and the same thing happens. A flash of something and no output. Does that conclude anything? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
FOR /F %X ('texteditor --help') DO ECHO %X
```

This *should* take the output from texteditor and echo it, line by line, on the console. If you're going to put it in a batch file, double the percent symbols.